# CSS Background Image Cut Off

Tags: css

I've looked at a other similar thread and can't seem to find the answer.

Look at the shield background image. It's cut off slightly at the top and bottom... I've tried a lot of things but I can't get it to display properly.

Here is the site http://revivedlife.com

Here's the css for the background image:

```
.hentry h2 {
    background: url(images/post_element.png) no-repeat 0 -4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code within your question, otherwise when your problem is resolved this question will be completely meaningless to future visitors.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Could you please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Make sure you post code that is relevant to your question. We can't tell what the problem is if you don't.

Comment: @jabbathehutt1234 Posted

Comment: @AshleyMiriam cool, thank you!

Comment: @jabbathehutt1234 Why is my question a -1?

Comment: @AshleyMiriam I'm not sure. Most likely someone though your post was low quality and didn't give it a change to get edited. Make sure you read through all the help pages  before you ask questions, this will result in much higher quality posts.

Comment: @AshleyMiriam Also, if you want a friendlier community for asking questions (better for beginners) I would recommend http://askjelly.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried background-size: cover;

I think the following code may help you :)

```
.hentry h2 {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("http://revivedlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bg_body.jpg");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It's not the main page background image. It's the shield icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your existing css with this:

```css
.hentry h2 { 
  background: url(LOCATION HERE) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This will make sure the background image looks correct, even on old browsers.

Comment: That exploded the size of the background image icon.

Comment: Hmm... do you want it to fill up it's whole space?